# render @items and no routes matches error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :lists, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :wishes, through: :lists
  has_many :items, through: :wishes

class List < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :wishes, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :items, through: :wishes

class Wish < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :list
  belongs_to :item

class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :wishes
  has_many :lists, through: :wishes
```

My problem occurs when I want to show the `items` associated with a `List`. I get the error:

```
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"items", :id=>#<Item id: nil, title: nil, link: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil, image: nil>}
```

It is as if it is trying to show an `Item` which does not exist, because I have just one `Item` in the database.

```
class ListsController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @list = @user.lists.find(params[:id])
    @item = @list.items.build if current_user?(@user)
    @items = @list.items
  end
```

app/view/lists/show.html.erb

```
  <div class="span8">
    <% if @list.items.any? %>
      <ol class="lists white-box">
        <%= render @items %>
      </ol>
    <% end %>
  </div>
```

app/view/items/_item.html.erb

```
<li>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <a class="thumb" href="<%= item_path(item) %>">
            <%= image_tag item.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
        </a>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <span class="content">
            <%= item.title %>, <%= item.link %>
          </span>
          <span class="timestamp">
            Created <%= time_ago_in_words(item.created_at) %> ago.        
            <% if current_user?(item.lists.last.user) %>
            <%= link_to "delete", item, method: :delete,
                                        data: { confirm: "You sure?" },
                                        title: item.title %>
            <% end %>
          </span>

        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

**Additional**

If i change `app/view/items/_item.html.erb` to this:

```
<li>
    <div class="clearfix">
        <a class="thumb" href="#">
            <%= image_tag item.image_url(:thumb).to_s %>
        </a>
        <div class="clearfix">
          <span class="content">
            <%= item.title %>, <%= item.link %>
          </span>    
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

The page is rendered, but shows this as if it tries to render an `Item` which does not exist:

[image: First line is the Item from the database, the second line appears to be an empty Item entry]

**Edit**

In my `app/view/lists/show.html.erb` I have `<%= render 'shared/item_form' %>` for building an Item.

_item_form.html.erb looks like this:

```
<% if signed_in? %>

  <div id="addWish" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="addWishLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
      <h3 id="addWishLabel">Add wish</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <%= form_for(@item, html: { multipart: true }) do |f| %>
      <div class="field">
        <%= render 'items/fields', f: f %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag :list_id, @list.id %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
      <%= f.submit "Add", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
      <% end %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your controller is building an empty item - see `@item = @list.items.build if current_user?(@user)`. Your view correctly cannot generate a link to this unsaved item.

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't think that was causing the problem. However, I want to be able to build an `Item` for the `List` show action. And I have a partial for doing that - see updated question.

Comment: That's fine. You can do that in the view instead (eg. `form_for @list.items.build`) or you can generate an item manually (eg. `@item = Item.new(list: @list)`.